# Unicode Locale Data Markup for (e.g.) "Tue, 23 Feb 2010 06:00:44 PST"

Tags: cocoa, unicode, date, formatting, nsdateformatter

I was parsing a XML feed and trying to convert it to a NSObject when I noticed that  (e.g.) `[NSDate dateFromString:@"Tue, 23 Feb 2010 06:00:44 PST"]` returned `nil`. Then I tried to convert my string to a `NSDate` by using the `NSDateFormatter`.

```
NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[df setDateFormat:@"EEE, dd MMM YYYY HH:mm:ss zzz"];
NSDate *d = [df dateFromString:@"Tue, 23 Feb 2010 06:00:44 PST"];
```

But this still returns `nil`. I think my problem is that my [Unicode Data Markup](http://unicode.org/reports/tr35/#Date_Format_Patterns) is wrong. I have no idea how it should look like.
For more information about the `Unicode Locale Data Markup Language` look [here](http://unicode.org/reports/tr35/#Date_Format_Patterns).

Thank you for every of your ideas!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The formatter was set to the wrong locale.

```
[df setLocale:[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US"]];
```

This helped. I also changed "YYYY" to "yyyy". The solution was found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2230047/why-my-nsdate-formatter-cant-convert-correctly-and-returns-null-on-device).