# iOS NSDate and NSManagedObject

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, ios5

Having a very odd problem. After processing of a file I read a txt which has three lines. Version, From Datetime, ToDatetime. I read these lines and add an object to NSCoreData. Everything works fine when running in a simulator but as soon as I deploy to my iPhone the NSDates come back as null.

Here is the console output when running from iPhone

```
2012-01-05 23:58:25.478 FlightPath[10257:707] 7/28/2011 12:00:00 AM
2012-01-05 23:58:27.911 FlightPath[10257:707] (null)
2012-01-05 23:58:29.718 FlightPath[10257:707] (null)
```

Here is the console output when running form iPhone Sim

```
2012-01-06 00:07:07.900 FlightPath[1755:11903] 7/28/2011 12:00:00 AM
2012-01-06 00:07:08.899 FlightPath[1755:11903] 7/28/2011 12:00:00 AM
2012-01-06 00:07:11.686 FlightPath[1755:11903] 7/28/2011 12:00:00 AM
```

Here is the code...I added in tDate for testing purposes. I wanted to make sure i didn't need to add __block to the NSManagedObject.

```
NSString *mapInfoPath = [[mapData objectAtIndex:1] stringByAppendingPathComponent: @"Tiles/info.txt"];
        NSString *mapInfo = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:mapInfoPath encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
        __block NSDate *tDate = nil;
        NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"M/d/yyyy h:mm:ss a"];

        __block int lineCount = 0;                
        [mapInfo enumerateLinesUsingBlock:^(NSString *line, BOOL *stop) {
            switch (lineCount) {
                case 1:
                    map.editionNumber = [NSNumber numberWithInt:[line intValue]];
                    break;
                case 2:   
                    tDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:line]; 
                    map.fromDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:line];
                    NSLog(@"%@", line);
                    NSLog(@"%@", [dateFormatter stringFromDate:map.fromDate]);
                    NSLog(@"%@", [dateFormatter stringFromDate:tDate]);
                    break;
                case 3:                            
                    map.toDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:line];
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }

            lineCount += 1;
        }];
        map.processed = [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES];
```

Any help would be great....stuck and can't figure out why it works on sim and not iPhone.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Appears this is a bug when phone is in 24 hour mode. The direct answer was here: http://multinc.com/2009/09/27/iphone-sdk-time-bug-for-international-users/ which I found off of this post: [Why my NSDate Formatter can't convert correctly and returns null on device?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2230047/why-my-nsdate-formatter-cant-convert-correctly-and-returns-null-on-device)

Since I always know I'll be parsing a 12hr date time I just used setLocale and that did the trick.

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setLocale: [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US"]];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"M/d/yyyy h:mm:ss aa"];
```